# Select actual heigth

Tags: sql, database

There is a table with people, height and date of measurement

```
Name    Height  Date
---------------------------
John    160     01.02.2015
Jack    150     01.02.2015
Jessica 145     01.02.2016
John    165     01.02.2016
```

How to select people and height with only actual (date maximum)

Comment: With that data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method for getting the most recent record uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

This works best with an index on `(name, date)`.